# What is the best way to set a variable with an if, else if, else statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

There has to be a better way to set the variable $callLinkContainer in the following code block:

```
var $callLinkContainer;
if ( $callLink.closest('class1-tel').length > 0 ) {
     $callLinkContainer = $('body').find('.class1-container');
} else if ( $callLink.closest('.class2').length > 0 ) {
     $callLinkContainer = $('body').find('.class2-container');
} else {
     $callLinkContainer = $callLink.closest('.class3');
}
```

Previously, I had used a ternary operator to set the variable, but I'm pretty sure the third condition makes that impossible. I'd like to make this code more concise if it's possible to do so.

Comment: Why do you need `$('body').find(...)` in the first two assignments?

Comment: This is just a snippet from a much larger piece of code. I'm basically looking for data-attributes on containers of links and setting the variable to that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest conditional operators. The code is shorter, and with appropriate line breaks and indentation it's as readable as the `if` statements.

```
$callLinkContainer = $callLink.closest('class1-tel').length ?
    $('.class1-container') :
    ($callLink.closest('.class2').length ?
        $('.class2-container') :
        $callLink.closest('.class3'));
```

Comment: FWIW, you can remove the `> 0`s

Comment: You can safely break this into multiple lines to improve readability - semicolon inference won't get in the way.

Comment: I did break it into multiple lines.

Comment: OK, now I've broken it into more lines -- it is indeed more readable.

Comment: Please don't do that even if it is on multiple lines. That's horribly unreadable. There's nothing wrong with a few if statements if it dramatically simplifies your code.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I wanted to see.

Comment: The parenthesis are not required, though useful for clarity

Comment: The associativity of ternary operators isn't intuitively obvious to me, so I use parentheses to ensure proper grouping.

Comment: @AurélienGasser - PHP programmers have to use parens around the `?` operator because precedence is broken in PHP.  I kind of encourage everyone to use parens there, just for sanity.

Answer (score 2):

You can use several ternary operators with indentation

```
var $callLinkContainer = $callLink.closest('class1-tel').length > 0 
  ? $('body').find('.class1-container')
  : $callLink.closest('.class2').length > 0 
    ? $('body').find('.class2-container')
    : $callLink.closest('.class3');
```

The priority of the operators is so that you don't need to add parenthesis like in

```
a ? b : (c ? d : e)
```

You might want to add them for extra clarity, though.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to do the next suggestion

1. Encapsulate the code in several functions

   ```
   function isCallLinkClosest(var callLinkSelector){ 
       return $callLink.closest(callLinkSelector).length > 0;
   }

   function getCallLinkContainer(var containerSelector){
       return $('body').find(containerSelector);
   }

   function getDataAttributeByClass(){ 
       if ( isCallLinkClosest('class1-tel')) {
        return getCallLinkContainer('.class1-container');
       } else if ( isCallLinkClosest('.class2')) {
        return getCallLinkContainer('.class2-container');
       } else {
        return $callLink.closest('.class3');
       }
   }
   ```

This is the best suggestion that I can do with the given information :)

Answer (score 0):

Do `.class1-tel`, `.class2` or `.class3` exist at the same time?
If not, then you could possibly do something like this:

```
var $callLinkContainer = ($callLink.closest('.class1-tel, .class2').length
    ? $('body').find('.class1-container, .class2-container')
    : $callLink.closest('.class3'));
```

If you could be more specific about class names and dom structure, the code could be even easier.